# Are variables inside functions destroyed and re-initialized everytime the function is called?

Tags: python-3.x, function, performance, memory, scope

I apologize I don't quite know the best way to word this question:

For the sake of simplicity, If I have a function:

```
def add_number(num):
    to_add = 2 + 4
    return to_add + num
```

and the main:

```
def __main__():
    add_number(5)
    add_number(10)
    add_number(25)
```

is the variable `to_add` destroyed when the program leaves the function scope, and reinitialized everytime the function is called? Meaning in this case, is the 2+4 calculated 3 times? Or is it cached in memory by the interpreter.

Obviously, in this example there is little downside to `to_add` being calculated each time, but if the function were to be called hundreds of times, and if `to_add` required many more operations to calculate it would slow the program down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see exactly what the interpreter is doing with your code with the `dis` module.

As you can see from the disassembly of `add_number()`:

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis(add_number)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (6)
              2 STORE_FAST               1 (to_add)

  3           4 LOAD_FAST                1 (to_add)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (num)
              8 BINARY_ADD
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

The variable `to_add` is bound in the local namespace at the beginning of the function each time it runs. However, you'll notice that `2+4` has already been simplified to `6` by the compiler.

If `to_add` were a more complex expression, it's possible you might get a performance increase by setting `to_add` outside the function, so it only has to be calculated and bound once.